# Yii: How to display a custom view for exception generated during an ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, exception, yii

Is it possible to call my own controller action to handle the display of exception error messages on an Ajax request?

A wiki has been written on this topic on the Yii website, but it appears to be out of date. The class CErrorHandler appears to have changed since the author wrote the wiki. The wiki recommends adding the following component property to the config file:

```
'errorHandler' => array(
    'errorAction' => 'site/error',
),
```

This controller action is never reached though because CApplication::displayError() is called in CErrorHandler.

```
if($this->isAjaxRequest())
    $app->displayError($event->code,$event->message,$event->file,$event->line);
```

Back to my original question, can I set up my own controller action to handle the display of error messages on an Ajax request?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make something like this:

```
$handler=$app->getErrorHandler();
$handler->errorAction='my/error';
```

Didn't test this but might work.

Also you can just push error to ajax success call.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve what you want to do is replace (or extend) the `CErrorHandler` class.

Most probably, you would have to re-implement either `handle($event)` or `handleException` or `handleError`. However, you could also modify `isAjaxRequest` to always return false, this way it'll just behave as usual.

These are the steps you would need to do:

In `protected/ErrorHandler.php`:

```
<?php
/**
 * ErrorHandler is the customized error handler for the application.
 */
class ErrorHandler extends CErrorHandler {
    public function handle($event) {
            // do something special ...
        parent::handle($event);
    }
    // more special things ...
}
```

In `protected/config/main.php`:

```
return array(
    // ...
    'components'=>array(
        // ...
        'errorHandler'=>array(
            'class' => 'ErrorHandler',
            // ...
            ),
        // ...
    ),
    // ...
);
```

I hope it helps!